# google: HOw to expire a catcha token after the request fails

Tags: recaptcha-v3

I am using a google captcha for my login page.

The catcha when verified by human it will generate a token, which we pass to the backend server along with the username and pass.

The backend server will verify the captcha and then only it will check if username and pass is correct

I heard that the captcha token is valid for 2min.

But if username and password are not right, i want to expire that captcha token.

How to expire the captcha token

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the state of the token, but you can change your logic a little and check the token separately from your login system. This way, if the person doesn't manage to log in, you ask them to redo the captcha (which you can reset).